# What happens if I shard a collection which already has documents in it?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, sharding

I have a collection with a lot of documents. I shared that collection. I have 2 shard clusters. But yet all documents reside in the primary shard cluster. Why it is not split into different shards?
100 % of data is still in the primary shard

Comment: What is "a lot of documents"?

Comment: How many chunks are there?